# Kid wants to pilot space liner, is too ugly

Tags: story-identification

This is a story from sometime in or before the early 1980s. The gist is that there's a kid who spends his whole life dreaming about being the pilot of a space-going passenger craft. However he can't because all the pilots are tall, handsome, square-jawed and so on, and he's a complete six-stone weakling and ugly as sin, albeit very skilled.

However he triumphs in the end because it turns out that these ships are actually piloted by guys like him, hidden in the bowels of the ship and plumbed in to the computers, and the good-looking fly-boy types are actually all as dumb as rocks and just there for show, and to make the passengers feel comfortable.

I have a feeling that this might have been a one-off strip in 2000AD comic, although it could also have been in an SF anthology of some kind. Ringing any bells ?

Comment: This isn't it I am sure, but this basically describes the plot of the movie Gattaca, except that in the movie the "tall, handsome, square-jawed ...jocks" are genetically engineered and are also very smart.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. Sounds very much like Gattaca. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119177/

Comment: This isn't like Gattaca. That's a movie about genetic modification. The main character is a natural born baby with no genetic modifications which leaves him with a heart murmur that keeps him from joining this space exploration program. He wasn't even trying to be a pilot. This story sounds completely different from Gattaca.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm talking a story written before the early 80s.

Comment: @KevinHowell Hence the comment, and the preface of "This isn't it I am sure"

Comment: @NominSim and my point is that this story that Alan B describes is nothing like Gattaca except for both the main characters want to go into space. Other than that the plots are completely different.

Comment: @KevinHowell You must not have seen the movie in a while :), anyways thanks for reiterating my statement that he wasn't talking about Gattaca.

Comment: In the not-too-distant future, a less-than-perfect man wants to travel to the stars. Society has categorized Vincent Freeman as less than suitable given his genetic make-up and he has become one of the underclass of humans that are only useful for menial jobs. He assumes the identity of Jerome Morrow, a perfect genetic specimen who is a paraplegic as a result of a car accident. With professional advice, Vincent learns to deceive DNA and urine sample testing. Just when he is finally scheduled for a space mission, his program director is killed , jeopardizing his secret. -Gattaca. Nothing alike.

Comment: @NominSim I have seen this movie over 20 times. So are you intentionally playing dumb or do you really not grasp how different the two stories are? So much to the point that you shouldn't have even said "but this basically describes the plot to Gattaca" And further claiming that I haven't seen the movie in awhile is a childish quip that probably makes you feel smug but really does not address the fact that the stories are completely different. I haven't missed anything. I've explained in detail how they are different. You haven't explained anything. No more comments needed argue w/ me in chat.

Comment: @KevinHowell You don't seem to be really taking this to heart; I put my response as a comment (read: NOT an answer) and even prefaced it with "This isn't it I am sure" The plot the OP described was similar enough to Gattaca that I thought they would be interested to know about it, with the reasoning that if they enjoyed the story they are looking for they may enjoy a similar story. As far as "grasping how different the two stories are", here is the OP's post with (very) slight changes that make it into the plot of Gattaca:

Comment: "This is a story from [the future]. The gist is that there's a kid who spends his whole life dreaming about being [involved in the space program]. However he can't because all the pilots are tall, handsome, square-jawed and so on, and he's [normal], albiet very skilled. 

However he triumphs in the end because it turns out that [insert spoiler from end of movie here]."

Comment: Dammit, I was just typing up this exact question when yours was suggested - your question is exactly what I was about to ask, but you haven't actually received a decent answer which answers the question so Im not sure what to do now :/ This was definitely in a 1980s 2000AD annual book.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the story "The Volunteer" from the 1982 2000AD Annual.

Byron Z. Gymp was a poor example of a man, barely touching 5 feet tall with thick socks, a misshapen nose, a limp and a very bad pair of lazy eyes, yet all he wanted to do was pilot a starliner.  But star liner pilots were handsome, 6 foot tall men with chiseled chins.

His repeated attempts to fool the star liner recruitment office are always foiled, and in his desperation he finally breaks into the ship yard, intending to steal a star liner, but in doing so he discovers the real secret...

[image: Byron, in all his glory]

A few quotations from the story:

> "There's
> future for you in Laker Spacelines", It
> proudly blared, showing a picture of a tall, handsome
> Starliner Captain welcoming his passengers on board.
> The scene switched to the liner's flight deck
> The immaculate Captain opened the warp-drive
> controls to maximum and the ship surged forward.
> If you are over six feet tall, of a pleasant appearance and feel that a liner pilot is the job for YOU, call at ou
> recruiting centre TODAY!" The man on the screen
> turned a sickeningly bright and even smile to the
> camera and the advert faded out.

and later on, after Byron has attempted to steal a starliner and discovered the flight deck was a fake:

> Byron was still recovering from the shock as
> Knowles led him back outside the ship and under her
> nose. There was a bigger shock waiting for him there:
> he thought at first that the figure standing there was a
> robot--it was about his height and he had never seen
> anything SO ugly, there were wires and tubes and
> connectors coming out all over it. But underneath all
> the metal and plastic there was flesh. Flesh bonded
> directly to metal and plastic. It was half man, half
> machine cyborg.
> The creature walked under the nose to the circular
> bulged dome that Byron had always thought was a radar scanner.

[image: Byron at the end of the story]

The Annual should be available second hand from Ebay or comic book dealers, or can be found online.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Sounds a lot like the [Brain & Brawn series from Anne McCaffrey et alii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang#Brain_.26_Brawn_Ship_series) (Wiki link)

The premise is that  children who are deformed but with otherwise healthy brains can be transplanted into "shells" (a reinforced life support cylinder for the brain only), they become the "brains" of the ships.  They are partnered with "brawns" who provide the physical part of the deal.

Comment: It does indeed and I suspect the one I am thinking of may have 'borrowed' the concept. Will investigate further ...

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm thinking of so I'm going to accept this as the answer.