# Mining in space: a group of miners, and computers nerds as support crew

Tags: story-identification, space

I'm trying to find the title of a movie which is based around a mining operation in space.

There are two main groups of people working. One lot are the actual miners who are a fairly rough bunch and then there are their support crew which are basically computer nerds who stay at the base and help coordinate. The miners tend to pick on the nerds a lot and eventually one gets killed. The other nerds take revenge by spiking the killer's food with a pill that sends him psychotic and then eventually kills him. Things get worse from there on in and eventually all the nerds have to equip themselves with the pills to scare off any further attacks.

Comment: Duplicate of the following:http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33106/space-film-about-pilots-and-navigators/33110#33110

Comment: @beichst I don't see how?  Moon 44 is missing many aspect's of what the querent describes.

Comment: @Tritium21. Interesting. I am curious which aspect(s) you believe don't match.  From a quick review Moon 44 includes: Mining operation in space, Check. Rough group of miners/pilots (a.ka. prisoners) and group of computer nerds, Check. Rough miners/prisoners pick on nerds and one dies, Check (This is actually a violent prison rape scene that causes the victim respond by killing the rapist/pilot then to commit suicide), Check.  When the rough prisoners threaten the nerds, the nerds poison the rough miner nearly killing him, Check.  This occurs in the lunch room. Check.

Comment: When the rough prisoners again threaten the nerds, they all hold up additional pill bags threatening back. The quote goes something like: "We control the food, the water, the air. If you hurt us, we will kill you."  At that point a "truce" of sorts is struck and the groups manage to work together.

Comment: If you want, you can check out the clips at the DailyMotion sites.  Item two below starting at about timestamp 11 - 13 describes the pill scene above. 
http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1107mb_moon-44-1990-1_shortfilms

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1109jt_moon-44-1990-2_shortfilms

Comment: @beichst How about "its a stretch to fit what the querent listed with the movie you intend to close their question with, when another movie already posted in an answer fits the question almost verbatim."  I would not have commented if there wasn't a much BETTER fit of a movie than in your comment to vtc-dup.  You made a WILD GUESS that it was a dupe based on hopefulness, and VTCed a question.

Answer (score 7):

It's quite possible the film you are looking for is 1981's "[Outland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outland_(film))", starring Sean Connery and Peter Boyle. It is set on an outer space Titanium mining outpost. The plot has drugs, hookers, murder and more. It's a western set in space. The only thing missing is the sound of spurs during the final showdown.

Answer (score 4):

[Moon 44](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097910/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) (1990) has space helicopters piloted by convicts and navigated by computer whiz kids. The setting is a corporate war for mining resources. I do remember the pilots picking on the nerds but I don't remember any psychotic drugs, but it has been many years since I watched it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_44), [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/moon_44/).

Comment: Greenstone Walker is correct. This is definitely Moon 44. This is a duplicate of a previous question at: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33106/space-film-about-pilots-and-navigators/33110#33110